# How to setup Shopify APP using React & NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify-api, shopify-api-node, shopify-app-bridge

1. I'm stuck for the last 5 days. I'm getting a provider error from
   '@shopify/app-bridge-react'. I created a new project but still got
   the same issues.
2. I'm using node 17.3.0 version.
3. dependencies veriosn are "dependencies": {
   "@shopify/app": "3.11.0",
   "@shopify/cli": "3.11.0"
   },

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ6Z0.png)

Comment: Update nodejs and that should solve it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].